# Page not found (404) Django. Defining url addresses

Tags: python, django

I'm doing this [tutorial](https://www.codementor.io/jadianes/get-started-with-django-building-recommendation-review-app-du107yb1a). Unfortunately, it is for a different version of Django (I use the latest version). I found a small problem with error 404, but I have no idea how to solve it. I am asking for help in solving it.

Error when I started my page 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/reviews/':

```
Using the URLconf defined in winerama.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

^$ [name='review_list']
^review/(?P<review_id>[0-9]+)/$ [name='review_detail']
^wine$ [name='wine_list']
^wine/(?P<wine_id>[0-9]+)/$ [name='wine_detail']
admin/
The current path, reviews/, didn't match any of these.
```

My views.py (app)

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from .models import Review, Wine

def review_list(request):
    latest_review_list = Review.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:9]
    context = {'latest_review_list':latest_review_list}
    return render(request, 'reviews/review_list.html', context)

def review_detail(request, review_id):
    review = get_object_or_404(Review, pk=review_id)
    return render(request, 'reviews/review_detail.html', {'review': review})

def wine_list(request):
    wine_list = Wine.objects.order_by('-name')
    context = {'wine_list':wine_list}
    return render(request, 'reviews/wine_list.html', context)

def wine_detail(request, wine_id):
    wine = get_object_or_404(Wine, pk=wine_id)
    return render(request, 'reviews/wine_detail.html', {'wine': wine})
```

My urls.py (app)

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

app_name = 'reviews'

urlpatterns = [
    # ex: /
    url(r'^$', views.review_list, name='review_list'),
    # ex: /review/5/
    url(r'^review/(?P<review_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.review_detail, name='review_detail'),
    # ex: /wine/
    url(r'^wine$', views.wine_list, name='wine_list'),
    # ex: /wine/5/
    url(r'^wine/(?P<wine_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.wine_detail, name='wine_detail'),
]
```

My urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

app_name = 'reviews'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('reviews.urls', namespace="reviews")),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

How to correct the code correctly. I understand that the error is in urls.py (app). Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Well where do you think you have defined a URL for "reviews"?

Comment: I am relatively new in Django, but I think the URL for  "reviews" is defined in My urls.py. in this place 'path('', include('reviews.urls', namespace="reviews"))' .

Comment: Well no it isn't, because you used an empty string there instead of "reviews".

Comment: Yes you have a right, I wrote my code urls.py for reviews  'path('reviews/', include('reviews.urls', namespace="reviews"))' and everything works good. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can see reviews on 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/'.

if you want to see review_list at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/reviews' then you can try this.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include, url

app_name = 'reviews'

urlpatterns = [
    # path('', include('reviews.urls', namespace="reviews")),
    # path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^reviews/', include('reviews.urls', namespace="reviews")),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```